# Chern class of rank one sheaves supported on subvarieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, chern-classes

Let $X$ be a smooth, quasi-projective variety of dimension $n$ and $\mathcal{F}$ be a globally generated coherent sheaf supported on a codimension two subvariety $V \subset X$. Is $c_2(\mathcal{F}) \not= 0$ in $A^2(X)$ or $H_{2n-4}(X)$? If necessary, assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is of rank one over $V$.

Comment: If $X$ is not projective then $A^2(X)$ could be zero, but there will always be sheaves as in the question (as long as $n \geq 2$). If $X$ is projective then the answer is yes. (Also, $2$ can be replaced by any non-negative integer and the globally generated condition is not needed.)

Comment: In fact, $c_2(F) = -r[V]$, where $r$ is the rank on $V$, so in the projective case it is non-zero.

Comment: @Sasha and naf: Thank you.